# Calculating Deciles with MySQL

Tags: mysql, percentile, quartile

I have a very simple table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS availables (   
   IdMat     TINYINT,  
   size      INT, 
PRIMARY KEY(IdMat ) )
```

There are 7 285 000 rows in this table.
I search the best approach to calculating 10 deciles based on number of size.

I do this simple, fast method to calculate the specified number of deciles:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `TEST`()
BEGIN

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableInMemory ENGINE=MEMORY AS (SELECT size FROM availables ORDER BY size ASC);
SELECT COUNT(size) INTO @myvar FROM tableInMemory ;

PREPARE STMT FROM "SELECT size INTO @rank FROM tableInMemory LIMIT ?,1;"; 
SET @x = 1;
WHILE @x  <= 9 DO
   SET @idx = FLOOR(@myvar * @x / 10) - 1;
   EXECUTE STMT USING @idx;
   SELECT @rank AS 'Value', COUNT(size) AS 'Count' FROM tableInMemory WHERE size < @rank;
   SET  @x = @x + 1; 
END WHILE;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;

END
```

I'm not sure that, this is the best / most effective approach.

Anyone can give me a hint?

Comment: This post has a good example query that you can try: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2008/07/mysql-percentile-aftermath-calculating.html

Comment: I know this topic but It doesn't work. I have also found this post http://rpbouman.blogspot.fr/2008/07/calculating-percentiles-with-mysql.html but I get few performance.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me: use of in-memory temp tables, prepared statements, short loop.